# How do I get alerted to an pending AD CS certificate request?

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

I want to get a summary report of pending AD CS requests.  How would I approach this? Does anything already exist?

[image]

The problem I'm trying to solve is where a user requests a certificate, and i'm unaware of this pending/outstanding item.

Comment: http://www.expta.com/2012/07/how-to-enable-notifications-for-pending.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to utilize ADCS SMTP Exit Module: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773129(v=ws.10).aspx
Exit module is more flexible than eventlog subscription. Though, eventlog subscription is suitable for low pofile CAs.